# Communicate with Flask without URL request

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I made a website which communicates with a Flask server, but it's using URL request for communication and that feels insecure and abusable. Plus, I'm sending complicated data (which contain slashes and line breaks) and large data.

So can I communicate with other ways?

Comment: This is a huge question not readily answered here.  Consider reading up on web application desgin first then coming up with a more specific question, or switching to a framework that doesn't force you to do it all yourself (such as Django).

Comment: Sounds like you want to use POST requests instead of GET requests: [how-to-get-and-parse-http-post-body-in-flask-json-and-form-data/](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-get-and-parse-http-post-body-in-flask-json-and-form-data/) Traditionally post requests contain form data but they can be used to send data in the request body - if you don't have a form to submit then you may just have to create the request body yourself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a big question with a lot of possible solutions. Here's my crack at it below:

I would not send large data through an HTTP request. Consider using an intermediate store such as an NFS cluster or AWS S3 to store your large, complicated data. Your producer server would then do the following:

1. Produce the data
2. Upload the data to the intermediate store
3. Send an HTTP request to your Flask server that just contains a file path to the data on the intermediate store

On receiving the HTTP request, your Flask server would do the following:

1. Authenticate the request as coming from the producer store (see below)
2. Verify that the path is on the intermediate store and not being exploited by an attacker to load data from a different source.
3. Load the data from the intermediate store at the given path
4. Process the data

Couple of things to consider:

- You need authentication between your producer and Flask server. Consider having your producer login to the Flask server at startup and gain a token. If you don't use authentication, anyone could upload a path for your Flask server to process. See: https://realpython.com/token-based-authentication-with-flask/
- It's a bad idea to have HTTP request processing threads take a long time. The thread can't be responding to other requests while it is processing data. Consider using [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/) workers to process large datasets instead of processing on the HTTP request thread. When your Flask server receives the HTTP request, spawn a task to process the data and immediately return to the user a status code such as [HTTP 202](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202). Your frontend can then either use polling, notifications or websockets to retrieve the results when ready.